# Logstash-Kafka integration not working

Tags: log4j, slf4j, logstash, apache-kafka

**We want to get logs using logstash and pass them to kafka.**

We have written the following conf file for logstash 1.5.0 beta 1 and kafka 2.9.2_0.8.1.1

**

```
input {    
         file {    
         type => "apache"    
         path => ["/var/log/apache2/access.log", "/var/log/apache2/error.log"]    
     }
}




output {    
    kafka {    
        codec => plain {    
            format => "%{message}"    
        }
    topic_id => "example1"    
    }    
}
```

**

After running the following command : **bin/logstash agent -f test.conf --log ex.log**

test.conf is our conf file.
ex.log is a blank file we have created for the logs to be stored.

we are getting the following output

Sending logstash logs to ex.log.
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.5.0.beta1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
Using milestone 1 output plugin 'kafka'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.5.0.beta1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http:  //logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http:/ /www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.**

We tried setting the CLASSPATH in bashrc. Did not work.
Please tell us where we are going wrong.
Thankyou in advance!

Comment: That's just a warning about the Kafka plugin's logging. I doubt it affects its function.

Comment: But our logs are anyway not getting transfered to kafka consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that you can check:
is the topic example1 available? If not did you use auto create in kafka? Check for existing topics like this:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Example1 should be between the returned items, if not you can create the topic manually as well.

```
bin/kafktopics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic example1
```

To see if kafka receives message start a consumer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic example1
```

I started a simple logstash instance that listens to the standard in and using the consumer I see if a message arrives in kafka. This is my logstash configuration:

```
input {
        stdin { }
}

output {
    kafka {
        codec => plain {
            format => "%{message}"
        }
        topic_id => "example1"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help! This worked!! :) We need to take input from a file. We cannot figure out how to do this. Could you help? We think we need to modify the kafka-console-consumer.sh as this file takes input from console.

Comment: We figured it out! Thank you!! :D

Comment: How did you resolve? Can you please post the solution?

Comment: here in the output you have taken kafka as output, please help me to configure elasticsearch as the output here.